# Why does a charge in the hollow of a conductor experience electrostatic force?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

Basically my question is why this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192281/347546, [https://osiris.df.unipi.it/~macchi/TEACHING/FISICA2/PROBLEMS/shellcharge.pdf](https://osiris.df.unipi.it/%7Emacchi/TEACHING/FISICA2/PROBLEMS/shellcharge.pdf) happens. What is the cause of the interaction of the charge with the sphere? Why is there electrostatic interaction in a system with only one charged body? The charge can't experience the influence of the same field it generates, and the induced electric field (whose role is to cancel interior field) in the conductor is zero out of it, am I right? So what other charged body does the charge interact with? Which potential does the charge interact with? What am I missing?

Comment: There are many charges in a neutral object. Just no net charge.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a physics teacher and someone else may have a better answer.

The claim is that electrons can move freely around the conductive sphere. So they will experience whatever electric forces there are, and move in precisely the ways that will equalize the potentials.

So if a charge is inside the hollow sphere, it will experience a constant potential no matter where it is inside the sphere, and since the force is the gradient of the potential, there will be no net force on it.

If an outside electric force is changing faster than the electrons in the conductor can move, then there will be transient forces. But charges in conductors can move pretty fast.

I've seen a [claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage#Exterior_fields) that the thickness of the conductive shell matters.

> What is the cause of the interaction of the charge with the sphere?

The charge attracts opposite charges on the sphere, and repels same charges. Since negative charges can move, the charge moves them.

> Why is there electrostatic interaction in a system with only one charged body?

There are lots of charges that can move, and the interaction is with the charges whether or not the sphere has the same number of positive and negative charges.

> So what other charged body does the charge interact with?

All of them. The charges on the conductive sphere also interact with all of them and move so the forces all average out to zero.

> Which potential does the charge interact with?

What you can easily measure is the movement of the charge due to the forces on it. Classical electromagnetic theory did not know about effects of potential on charges. Anyway, the charge interacts with the net potential due to all the other charges added together.

> What am I missing?

You might have the idea that the conductive sphere blocks all the electric fields from outside, so they do not interact with charges inside. It appears that instead the fields pass right through the sphere and do affect the inside charges. Just, the charges in the sphere move to positions where they cancel the outside forces.

Maybe somebody who knows more will correct me on this.

Comment: My question is: why does the charge in the hollow experience a force? As you say "it will experience a constant potential" and "there will be no net force on it", but this is in contrast with what the links I posted say: there's a force on the charge in the hollow

Comment: There are multiple forces on the charge inside. They cancel out to zero, but they are all there. You could calculate each of them. Just because there is an opposing force, does not mean any of them do not exist.